# How does the fmp4 file populate the esds box according to the ADTS of the AAC frame?

Tags: mp4, aac, adts, fmp4

My source AAC frame contains the ADTS header. I need to initialize the esds box in the fmp4 file according to the ADTS, cut out the ADTS header and fill in the rest data, but I have tried many times without success (the player can't parse out the audio).
The following is my ADTS data. Which parameters of the esds box I configured need to be modified?

ADTS

FF     1111  1111   0-7 bit

F9     1111  1001       8-15 bit        MPEG-2  no CRC

60     0110  0000       16-23 bit       AAC Main

40     0100  0000       24-27 bit

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you get that software (MP4 Reader)? I am not finding it to download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the adts to get the audio object type, frequency index, and channel count. Then write an audio specific config. https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/MPEG-4_Audio#Audio_Specific_Config

Comment: Thank you. I tried a few more times. It didn't work out yesterday